# Xcode Swift Parse Framework Installation Issue (Command PhaseScriptExecution failed)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm having lots of trouble installing the 'Parse' Cocoapod library/framework on Xcode. (version 10.3)

**What I did:**

After initializing a podfile with "pod init", and adding "pod 'Parse'" into the file, I ran "pod install" from terminal and integrated the pod into Xcode. There are no compiler errors and the pod library is showing up and looking fine with autocomplete working on it as well

**The issue:**

Upon trying to run the app, it gives me an error:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

More specifically, it gives me:

```
[filepath].../Pods-Real Estate App-frameworks.sh: eval: line 131: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

**Things I've tried already:**

- Completely reinstalling and reintegrating pods
- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting my computer
- Unlocking and relocking the login keychain
- I tried installing pods and bolts just by downloading the framework files but they generated different errors (I think because the two frameworks weren't linked together properly doing it that way? I couldn't figure out how to fix that either)

Answer (score 1):

Weird solution that I don't even know how I came across:

The issue was that a directory that contained my project had an apostrophe in it. I fixed it by renaming the directory, and then deleting the derived data folder in my project, cleaning the project and then running it.